# How does ASP.NET WebSecurity Authentication manages SQL Server connections?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, connection, security

I already have a EF Context in my ASP.NET MVC project. If I use WebSecurity I have these questions in my mind about its connection management to SQL Server .

- Does it use same connection with my EF model for that request? (I think not)
- Does it create another connection for every request? If so I will have two connections, one for EF the other for WebSecurity.
- If it use only one connection (since it can be placed into the Application_Start()), what if there are many users surfing the web at the same time? Will it lock other user requests and create a slowness?
- Does it make a check from database when it sees [Authorize] attribute on every request? (That makes like all pages where users need to be logged in.)

I would really appreciate about its internal mechanisms.

Note: **Please ignore connection pooling** unless WebMatrix/WebSecurity has an internal connection pooling.

Thanks.